# Elasticsearch + NEST: Use token-filter only for comparisation but not on analyzers result

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I want to build an analyzer in elasticsearch that ignores the cases of its input while comparisation but returns case sensitive results.

**This is my actual state:**

My NEST Code to create the analyzer

```
{ "MySynonymFilter", new SynonymTokenFilter { SynonymsPath = "Path/SynonymFile.txt", Lenient = true} },

{
    "MySynonymizer", new CustomAnalyzer
    {
        Tokenizer = "whitespace",
        Filter = new List<string> {"lowercase", "MySynonymFilter"}
    }
},
```

This is how the analyzer created above looks like:

```
"Synonymizer": {
    "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "MySynonymFilter"
     ],
    "type": "custom",
    "tokenizer": "whitespace"
},
```

My Synonymfile ("Path/SynonymFile.txt"):

```
one, two, three, four => FIVE
```

**This is actual result and desired result:**

Example query:

```
localhost:port/index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "MySynonymizer",
  "text":      "Input"
}
```

Actual result:

```
Input: "one"              Output: ["five"]
Input: "One tWo THREE"    Output: ["five", "five", "five"]
Input: "one TWO foo"      Output: ["five", "five", "foo"]
```

Result when the lowercase filter is removed:

```
Input: "one"              Output: ["FIVE"]
Input: "One tWo THREE"    Output: ["One", "tWo", "THREE"]
Input: "one TWO foo"      Output: ["FIVE", "TWO", "foo"]
```

Desired result:

```
Input: "one"              Output: ["FIVE"]
Input: "One tWo THREE"    Output: ["FIVE", "FIVE", "FIVE"]
Input: "one TWO foo"      Output: ["FIVE", "FIVE", "foo"]
```

Comment: You can't. Synonym filter use whatever filters preceding him to parse synonyms file.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up @MichaelIzvekov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) performs analysis on your input text and returns **tokens**. These tokens are the output of analyzer, but these are **not the final output**, we will use these tokens to perform the actual search.

---

What you want could have been achieved in the earlier version of Elasticsearch, using `ignore_case` parameter:

```
PUT /test_index
{
    "settings": {
        "index" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "filter" : {
                    "synonym" : {
                        "type" : "synonym",
                        "lenient": true,
                        "ignore_case": "true", // <-- deprecated
                        "synonyms" : ["one, two, three => FIVE"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you could analyze the text without using `"lowercase"` token filter:

```
GET /test_index/_analyze
{
  "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
  "filter" : ["synonym"] ,
  "text" : "One two three" // --> result: "FIVE", "FIVE", "FIVE"
}
```

So your synonyms would ignore case and the analyzer was not converting anything to lowercase... but `ignore_case` has been deprecated. If you try this code, you will get the following message:

> Deprecation: The ignore_case option on the synonym_graph filter is deprecated. Instead, insert a lowercase filter in the filter chain
>   before the synonym_graph filter.

What you want to achieve is no longer possible (and it makes sense). If your search is case-sensitive, then your synonyms are case sensitive too... if you want to ignore case, then use `"lowercase"` token filter...